# POCO Id property not being found

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have my poco type class defined like so:

```
 [Elastictype(Name="doc", IdProperty="Id")]
 public class Doc{
      public string Id;
      public string Name;
      ....
 }
```

However it still generates a random hash id instead in my .Index() request, though the id property does get saved in the document.

I tried it with and without the Elastictype defined, still same results.

The only way i was able to get it to work was by explicitly setting defining the id in the .Index request, which i wasnt able to find possible in bulk operations. Can someone tell me why my POCO id isnt being identified by NEST and how to enable it? Or how to explicitly set an id in my bulk request?

Comment: Constrol Freak I think this is because you are using `fields` and not `properties` can you post a github issue on this so that we can take the discussion on supporting this there?

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly set the Id during a Bulk Operation. I have used the following with success in the past:

```
  var docs = new List<Doc>();
  var bulkDescriptor = new BulkDescriptor;

  // assumes that docs has been populated...
  foreach(var doc in docs)
  {
      bulkDescriptor.Index<Doc>(op => op.Object(doc).Id(doc.Id));
  }

  //assumes using an already defined ElasticsearchClient
  var response = Client.Bulk(descriptor => bulkDescriptor);
```

Comment: Was actually able to figure this one out--Bulk w/id, but I'd still like to know why the Attribute initializer isn't recognizing the idproperty